# How to add dummy record in Oracle json_arrayagg

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, union, union-all

I have a simple Oracle database table with two columns, having this query

```
 select
          json_object( key 'clientTypes' VALUE
          (
                   select
                            json_arrayagg( json_object( key 'code' VALUE ct.code, key 'name' VALUE ct.name ) ORDER BY ct.code ASC )
                   from
                            CASINO.CLIENTTYPES ct
                   WHERE
                            ct.code != 'system'
          )
          returning clob ) responseJson
FROM
          DUAL
```

The result is single column with CLOB containing JSON Object with nested array

```
{
    "list": [{
        "code": 1,
        "name": "abc"
    },
    {
        "code": 2,
        "name": "def"
    }]
}
```

I need to add single dummy record in resulting JSON Object to look like as bellow

```
{
        "list": [{
            "code": 1,
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "code": 2,
            "name": "def"
        },
        {  "code": dummy code,
           "name": "dummy name"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: You can't (shouldn't) try and have "code": variably be an integer and a string (if that's what you meant by `dummy code` - you didn't put `"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you just UNION ALL your dummy data in before you do the JSON conversion

For example take this:

```
from  CASINO.CLIENTTYPES ct
```

And make it

```
from (
  select systemcode, code, name from casino.clienttypes    
  union all
  select 'x', -1, 'dummy name' from dual
) ct
```

If you want code to say 'dummy code' you'll need to do a TO_CHAR on your  actual numeric  code from the clienttypes table eg `TO_CHAR(code) as code`